# Reading a text file and combinig 2 lines into one using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am fairly new to python. I am trying to use regular expressions to match specific text in a file.

I can extract the data but only one regular expression at a time since the both values are in different lines and I am struggling to put them together. These severa lines repeat all the time in the file.

```
[06/05/2020 08:30:16] 
othertext           <000.000.000.000>    xx s 
example           <000.000.000.000>      xx s
```

I managed to print one or the other regular expressions:

```
[06/05/2020 08:30:16]
```

or

```
example           <000.000.000.000>      xx s
```

But not combined into something like this:

```
(timestamp)             (text) 
[06/05/2020 08:30:16]   example           <000.000.000.000>      xx s
```

These are the regular expressions

```
regex = r"^\[\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\]" #Timestamp
regex = r"(^example\s+.*\<000\.000\.000\.000\>\s+.*$)" # line that contain the text
```

This is the code so far, I have tried a secondary for loop with another condition but seem that only match one of the regular expression at a time.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

```
import re
filename = input("Enter the file: ")
regex = r"^\[\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\]" #Timestamp


with open (filename, "r") as file:
        list = []
        for line in file:
            for match in re.finditer(regex, line, re.S):
                match_text = match.group()
                list.append(match_text)
                print (match_text)
```

Comment: Do you want to match all lines as a separate match under the timestamp? Or match the timestamp in 1 match and all followed lines combined in the second?

Comment: Do you have blocks of text that follow this pattern? You can use a lookahead to match blocks of text up to the next start of a block.

Comment: Sorry, I am editing to make a bit more clear 
I tried to create two groups match and join the results but honestly I am not sure if that is even the correct way to approach this problem.

Comment: What I mean is that there are multiple lines following the timestamp. Do you want a single line, or match all the lines that come after the timestamp?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Okay I got you! There are several lines after the timestamp but I only interested in one specific line either the line example or either the line othertext so ideally the result should be: Timestamp + line or as close as that.

Answer (score 1):

You can match blocks of text similar to this in one go with a regex of this type:

```
(^\[\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d[ ]+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\])\s+[\s\S]*?(^example.*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6LTxlQ/1/)

All the file's text needs to be 'gulped' to do so however.

The key elements of the regex:

```
[\s\S]*?
   ^                idiomatically, this matches all characters in regex
      ^             zero or more
       ^            not greedily or the rest of the text will match skipping 
                    the (^example.*) part
```

Comment: Okay that regular expression blew my mind. 

I was approaching this as a two matching expressions and then joining then and I was getting pretty frustated. 

Thanks a lot! I am going to use this approach as the block of text repeat consistently through the file and I think I can it from there with this. Again thanks a million!